# Why am I reading less than nominal voltage on my receptacle?

Tags: receptacle

My master bathroom receptacle is showing the following voltages: Ground to Phase = 120.9V,  Ground to Neutral = 17.2V, and Phase to Neutral 94.6V. My question is why am I getting only 94.6 volts between Phase and Neutral?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Beware: garden-variety DVMs can read phantom voltages rather than real ones. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: Do other outlets in your home read similar values?

Comment: Are you experiencing any problems?

Comment: Is there a specific problem you are trying to solve? Is something not working correctly, like a hair dryer? Voltage readings can be quite "off" if there is no load on the circuit. If possible, plug an old fashioned incandescent lamp into the same circuit, turn it on and take your voltage readings again.

Comment: Is this the only place you have a low reading 17v on a neutral to ground is high is this a multi wire branch circuit?

Answer (score 1):

you have dropped a neutral.

the white wire is gone.

also called a loose neutral.

check all receptacles on the circuit.

if its only the one. turn off power and check the wiring is tight.

if its tight replace

if its loose tighten. (you should replace anyways. loose connection could have caused damage)

if its all of them and you notice that lights are a little dim in that area of the house. start at the breaker panel and work your way through he circuit checking for loose connections.

a 3light plug checker may read hot-ground reversed on an open neutral not open neutral.

the good news is that your nice and grounded.